# Do multiple regex changes in one update with the help of plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql, postgresql-performance

I'm looking for some tips to get this PostgreSQL plpgsql function to work. I would like to do a couple of regex's on each record and update only one time as doing them one by one takes 15 min. ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clean_column() RETURNS void  AS $$
    DECLARE
        r record;
        reg text[] := array[ 
          ['search','replace'], 
          ['search','replace'],
          ['search','replace'],
          ['search','replace'] 
        ];
        var text[];
        tmp text;
    BEGIN
        for r in 
            select column from mytable
            loop -- loop over all records
                tmp = r;
                FOREACH var SLICE 1 IN ARRAY reg
                LOOP -- loop over all changes
                    tmp = regexp_replace(tmp,var[1],var[2]);
                END LOOP;
                UPDATE mytable SET r = tmp;
        end loop;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

... there is a problem with r as it is not assigned. Probably my lack of understanding of how plpgsql works.

Maybe there is an other way to do multiple changes on a record field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function would update the row repeatedly, writing a new row version every time. That would still be hugely inefficient.

The point must be to update every row only ***once***. And only if anything actually changes.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clean_column(INOUT _text text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _reg CONSTANT text[] := ARRAY[ 
       ['search','replace']
     , ['search','replace']
     , ['search','replace']];
   _var text[];
BEGIN
   FOREACH _var SLICE 1 IN ARRAY _reg
   LOOP
      _text := regexp_replace(_text, _var[1], _var[2]);
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

The function does not run the `UPDATE` itself, just the string processing. Use that function in your `UPDATE` like so:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    col = clean_column(col)
WHERE  col IS DISTINCT FROM clean_column(col)  -- ① !
AND    col IS NOT NULL  -- ② ?
```

① Skip updates that would not change anything.

② Skip rows with `NULL` early (without even evaluating the function). Only relevant if column can be `NULL`, of course.

Performance will differ by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thank you Erwin. This was indeed an order of a magnitude quicker (3 sec now!!!) only thing I needed to change was AND col != '' instead of the NULL.

Comment: @BastiaanWakkie: Cool! For the record, a regex *could* replace the empty string with something, so use `col <> ''` only if you don't have such a regex. BTW, if your set of regex is fixed, a string of nested replacements in plain SQL should be faster, yet.